# Normalize the output signal to the same level as the input signal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, normalization

I have a **beamforming algorithm**,and I use matlab to **simulate data** so that I can estiamte 'ratio of **output signal-to-interference-plus-noise** ratio (SINR) to **input SINR** ([Like Matlab Does](https://cn.mathworks.com/help/phased/examples/acoustic-beamforming-using-a-microphone-array.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop)) .

```
agCbf = pow2db(mean((voice_cleanspeech+voice_laugh).^2+noisePwr)/...
    mean((cbfOut - voice_dft).^2))
```

Here comes my question. If I **mutiply** the output signal to some big number like 1000 (or just some changes  my algorithm introduced), then the ratio estimated is not right (because the `cbfOut` is much **bigger** than `voice_dft`). I want to know if there is any method to normalize the  output signal to the same level as the input signal.

I have seen **mapminmax** in matlab, this function can normalize both of them to `[-1 1]`, that's great but the result is **not zero means**.

Comment: First subtract the mean from the signal, then divide it by `max([max(signal), -min(signal)])`? Doing that will guarantee that the result has a `mean` of `0` and is strictly within `[-1 1]`

Comment: @Patrick Roberts  do you mean I do this after mapminmax ?or I just need to do it without mapminmax

Comment: I mean without `mapminmax`. All that does is restrict the range to `[-1 1]` without regard for the `mean`.

Comment: Thanks,that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before normalizing the output signal, you can demean it as follows:

```
signal = signal - mean(signal);
```

Once this is done and the signal has `mean = 0`, you can proceed with the normalization process between `-1` and `1`:

```
signal = mapminmax(signal);
```

Comment: Thanks,that helps me alot